# What's the difference between EventLoop in browsers and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log('promise2')
  setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout2'))
})
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('setTimeout1')
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise1'))
})
```

The result of running code in browser:

```
promise2 -> setTimeout1 -> promise1 -> setTimeout2
```

but in Node

```
promise2 -> setTimeout1 -> setTimeout2 ->promise1
```

Comment: Not sure about browsers but this is expected, documented behavior for Node: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, number three statements for discussion and identify the anonymous functions as `t1`, `t2`, `f1` and `f2` for timer (t) and fulfilled promise (f) callbacks:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => { // f2
  console.log('promise2')
  setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout2') /* t2 */)
})  // statement 1

setTimeout(() => {  // t1
  console.log('setTimeout1')
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise1'/* f1 */) // statement 3
}  // statement 2
```

Statement 1 places<sup>1</sup> `f2` is in the promise job queue (PJQ),
assuming `Promise.resolve` synchronously returns a fulfilled promise when its argument is not a promise or thenable. Calling `then` on a fulfilled promise dispatches execution of the fulfilled handler to the PJQ during the call, to be executed later when the promise job queue is processed.

Statement 2 places t1 in the timer call back queue.

<sup>1</sup> When executed, promise handlers are monitored by executor code for a promise returned by `then` or `catch`.

---

Process the queues in a browser, giving priority to the promise job queue:

```
PJQ:    f2
TimerQ: t1
```

call f2, log "promise2", add t2 to the timer queue

```
PJQ:     <empty>
Timers:  t1, t2
```

call t1, log "setTimeout1", execute statement 3, add f1 to the promise job queue.

```
PJQ:    f1
Timers: t2
```

call f1, log "promise1"

```
PJQ:    <empty>
timers: t2
```

call t2, log "setTimeout2".

So the logs appear as "promise2", "setTimeout1", "promise1", "setTimeout2" when the promise job queue has higher priority than timer call backs.

---

Process the queues where timer and promise jobs are processed in their order of creation, with no priority:

f2, t1

log "promise2", add t2

t1, t2

log "setTimeout1", add f1

t2, f1

log "setTimeout2"

f1

log "promise1"

So with equal priority, the logs are "promise2", "setTImeout1", "setTimeout2", "promise1" as reported for Node.

---

**TLDR;**

Browsers give priority to promise reaction jobs over timer callbacks. Node is consistent with giving timer and promise jobs equal priority but check the documentation.

It is a **veryBadIdea**<sup>(tm)</sup> to code promise architectures that rely on the priority given to timer callbacks and promise job queue execution. This can vary between host environments (browser vs node) and also between native Promise libraries and JavaScript promise libraries that are already in use or included as a polyfill for `Promise` in older browsers.